# I want my integers to stack in my JTextField

Tags: java, swing, if-statement, actionlistener, jtextfield

I have an actionperformed with 10 if and if else statements and in my JTextField inly one is displayed how would I have them stack to make numbers with more then one digits.

I don'd need anyone to read all of the code. I just want the ints from the actionPerformed to stack.

I am making a basic gui calculator.

```
    @Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    if(e.getSource().equals(oneButton)){
        input1 = 1;
        text.setText(""+input);}
    else if (e.getSource().equals(twoButton)){
        input2 = 2;
        text.setText(""+input);}
    else if(e.getSource().equals(threeButton)){
        input3 = 3;
        text.setText(""+input);}
    else if(e.getSource().equals(fourButton)){
        input4 = 4;
        text.setText(""+input);}
    else if(e.getSource().equals(fiveButton)){
        input5 = 5;
        text.setText(""+input);}
    else if(e.getSource().equals(sixButton)){
        input6 = 6;
        text.setText(""+input);}
    else if(e.getSource().equals(sevenButton)){
        input7 = 7;
        text.setText(""+input);}
    else if(e.getSource().equals(eightButton)){
        input8 = 8;
        text.setText(""+input);}
    else if(e.getSource().equals(nineButton)){
        input9 = 9;
        text.setText(""+input);}
    else if(e.getSource().equals(zeroButton)){
        input0 = 0;
        text.setText(""+input);}

}
```

**Rest Of My Code**

```
//imports
public class Ken implements ActionListener{


static JButton oneButton = new JButton("1");
static JButton twoButton = new JButton("2");
static JButton threeButton = new JButton("3");
static JButton fourButton = new JButton("4");
static JButton fiveButton = new JButton("5");
static JButton sixButton = new JButton("6");
static JButton sevenButton = new JButton("7");
static JButton eightButton = new JButton("8");
static JButton nineButton = new JButton("9");
static JButton zeroButton = new JButton("0");
static JButton minusButton = new JButton("-");
static JButton timesButton = new JButton("*");
static JButton enterButton = new JButton("=");
static JButton dividButton = new JButton("/");
static JButton plusButton = new JButton("+");
public static int input;
public static int input1;
public static int input2;   
public static int input3;
public static int input4;
public static int input5;
public static int input6;
public static int input7;
public static int input8;
public static int input9;
public static int input0;
public static JTextField text = new JTextField("0", 9);
public Ken(){

    JFrame frame = new JFrame("MyCalc");





    frame.setSize(476, 500);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setVisible(true);
    frame.setResizable(false);
    FlowLayout fl = new FlowLayout(0, 30, 20);
    setLayout(fl);
    Border empty;
    empty = BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder();

    frame.getContentPane().setLayout(fl);

    Container con = frame.getContentPane();
    con.setBackground(Color.LIGHT_GRAY);
    Font f = new Font("MS UI Gothic", Font.BOLD, 40);
    Font f2 = new Font("Engravers MT", Font.PLAIN, 40);
    int bHeight = 80;
    int bWidth = 70;
    text.setBackground(Color.GREEN);
    text.setFont(f2);
    text.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(bHeight, bWidth));
    text.setEditable(false);


    frame.add(text, BorderLayout.NORTH);

    oneButton.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(bHeight, bWidth));
    oneButton.setBackground(Color.DARK_GRAY);
    oneButton.setForeground(Color.GREEN);
    oneButton.setFont(f);
    oneButton.addActionListener(this);
    frame.add(oneButton);

    twoButton.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(bHeight, bWidth));
    twoButton.setBackground(Color.DARK_GRAY);
    twoButton.setForeground(Color.GREEN);
    twoButton.setFont(f);
    twoButton.addActionListener(this);
    frame.add(twoButton);

    threeButton.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(bHeight, bWidth));
    threeButton.setBackground(Color.DARK_GRAY);
    threeButton.setForeground(Color.GREEN);
    threeButton.setFont(f);
    threeButton.addActionListener(this);
    frame.add(threeButton);

    plusButton.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(bHeight, bWidth));
    plusButton.setBackground(Color.DARK_GRAY);
    plusButton.setForeground(Color.GREEN);
    plusButton.setFont(f);
    plusButton.addActionListener(this);
    frame.add(plusButton);

    fourButton.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(bHeight, bWidth));
    fourButton.setBackground(Color.DARK_GRAY);
    fourButton.setForeground(Color.GREEN);
    fourButton.setFont(f);
    fourButton.addActionListener(this);
    frame.add(fourButton);

    fiveButton.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(bHeight, bWidth));
    fiveButton.setBackground(Color.DARK_GRAY);
    fiveButton.setForeground(Color.GREEN);
    fiveButton.setFont(f);
    fiveButton.addActionListener(this);
    frame.add(fiveButton);

    sixButton.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(bHeight, bWidth));
    sixButton.setBackground(Color.DARK_GRAY);
    sixButton.setForeground(Color.GREEN);
    sixButton.setFont(f);
    sixButton.addActionListener(this);
    frame.add(sixButton);

    minusButton.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(bHeight, bWidth));
    minusButton.setBackground(Color.DARK_GRAY);
    minusButton.setForeground(Color.GREEN);
    minusButton.setFont(f);
    minusButton.addActionListener(this);
    frame.add(minusButton);

    sevenButton.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(bHeight, bWidth));
    sevenButton.setBackground(Color.DARK_GRAY);
    sevenButton.setForeground(Color.GREEN);
    sevenButton.setFont(f);
    sevenButton.addActionListener(this);
    frame.add(sevenButton);

    eightButton.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(bHeight, bWidth));
    eightButton.setBackground(Color.DARK_GRAY);
    eightButton.setForeground(Color.GREEN);
    eightButton.setFont(f);
    eightButton.addActionListener(this);
    frame.add(eightButton);

    nineButton.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(bHeight,bWidth));
    nineButton.setBackground(Color.DARK_GRAY);
    nineButton.setForeground(Color.GREEN);
    nineButton.setFont(f);
    nineButton.addActionListener(this);
    frame.add(nineButton);

    timesButton.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(bHeight, bWidth));
    timesButton.setBackground(Color.DARK_GRAY);
    timesButton.setForeground(Color.GREEN);
    timesButton.setFont(f);
    timesButton.addActionListener(this);
    frame.add(timesButton);


    zeroButton.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(bHeight, bWidth));
    zeroButton.setBackground(Color.DARK_GRAY);
    zeroButton.setForeground(Color.GREEN);
    zeroButton.setFont(f);
    zeroButton.addActionListener(this);
    frame.add(zeroButton);


    enterButton.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(190, bWidth));
    enterButton.setBackground(Color.DARK_GRAY);
    enterButton.setForeground(Color.GREEN);
    enterButton.setFont(f);
    enterButton.addActionListener(this);
    frame.add(enterButton);

    dividButton.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(bHeight, bWidth));
    dividButton.setBackground(Color.DARK_GRAY);
    dividButton.setForeground(Color.GREEN);
    dividButton.setFont(f);
    dividButton.addActionListener(this);
    frame.add(dividButton);

    frame.setComponentOrientation(
            ComponentOrientation.LEFT_TO_RIGHT);


}


private static Dimension Dimension(int bHeight, int bWidth) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}



private static void setLayout(FlowLayout fl) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}





public static void main(String[] args){

    new Ken();

}




@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    if(e.getSource().equals(oneButton)){
        input1 = 1;
        text.setText(""+input);}
    else if (e.getSource().equals(twoButton)){
        input2 = 2;
        text.setText(""+input);}
    else if(e.getSource().equals(threeButton)){
        input3 = 3;
        text.setText(""+input);}
    else if(e.getSource().equals(fourButton)){
        input4 = 4;
        text.setText(""+input);}
    else if(e.getSource().equals(fiveButton)){
        input5 = 5;
        text.setText(""+input);}
    else if(e.getSource().equals(sixButton)){
        input6 = 6;
        text.setText(""+input);}
    else if(e.getSource().equals(sevenButton)){
        input7 = 7;
        text.setText(""+input);}
    else if(e.getSource().equals(eightButton)){
        input8 = 8;
        text.setText(""+input);}
    else if(e.getSource().equals(nineButton)){
        input9 = 9;
        text.setText(""+input);}
    else if(e.getSource().equals(zeroButton)){
        input0 = 0;
        text.setText(""+input);}

}


}
```

Comment: I was about to show you how you can replace the 20 lines of code in your ActionListener with 2 lines of code, but since you still have all this code that is using `setPreferredSize()` I see you haven't listened to past suggestions so I won't bother making a suggestion this time. Also, all you variable are still static and I know other people advised you not to do this. So why do you even bother to post questions when you don't listen to the advice given?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use

```
text.setText(text.getText()+input);
```

instead of

```
text.setText(""+input);
```

because you're rewriting all of exists characters in text field.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what you mean, but think in this direction: extend the `JButton` with your own implementation of the button that will know its index:

```
private class MyButton extends JButton {

     private String index;

     public MyButton(String index) {
         this.index = index;
     }

     public String getIndex() {
         return index;
     }
}
```

Later on, you can do this for your `actionPerfmormed()` and no need for stacking up thousands of *ifs*:

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    if (e.getSource() instanceof MyButton) {
        text.setText(((MyButton)e.getSource()).getIndex());
    }
}
```